# c++ optimization of 2 lines of critical code

Tags: c++, optimization

With valgrind and perf/FlameGraphs I have identified part of my application which is consuming almost 100% of CPU:

```
for(size_t i = 0; i < objects.size(); i++) {

  //this part consumes 11% CPU -----> 
  collions_count = database->get_collisions(collisions_block, objects[i].getKey());
  feature1 = objects[i].feature1;
  //<--------

  for(int j = 0; j < collions_count * 2; j += 2) {

    hash = 
      ((collisions_block[j] & config::MASK_1) << config::SHIFT) | 
      ((collisions_block[j+1] - feature1) & config::MASK_2);

    if (++offsets[hash] >= config::THRESHOLD_1) {

      //... this part consumes < 1% of CPU

    }
  }
}
```

The calculation of hash and following if statement take nearly 90% of CPU of all application.

- `collisions_block` is initialized once and is of type `int[100000]`
- `config::` is a namespace with variables containing global  configuration
- `offsets` is initialized once and is of type `uint8_t[1<<24]`
- I am running Centos7 Linux 3.10.0-327.13.1.el7.x86_64
- all CPU is used for `usr` there is no `iowait` in mpstat output
- I am compiling with g++ (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-4) and flags `-std=gnu++11 -Ofast -Wall`

Is there any way to speed up the inner loop?

Comment: What is `feature1`?  Is it expensive to copy?  If it is can you make it a reference instead?

Comment: it is `int` and all 11% of CPU in that part is used by `get_collisions` call

Comment: I know this is not too helpful, but I don't think you can optimize those lines further... The problem is that you are just doing too many checks. If the logic is correct, then you should consider using a different data structure or algorithm. Without more info I couldn't say what would be the best way (if there is any)

Comment: What is a typical value of "collion_count", does it vary with i?

Comment: Also, `offsets` is a huge array that is being accessed with `hash`, that, I assume, does not have sequential values at all. That means caching is probably not working for that array, which would make the loop way slower. Not sure of a workaround for that though (maybe using a sparse data structure, e.g. a "default map", instead?)

Comment: @jdehesa By the very property of hashes, I don't think a workaround is possible...

Comment: Can you post the entire code please?

Comment: @0fnt collision_count is usually around ~4500 and it is very similar for each `i` and `objects.size()` around 450-500

Comment: @0fnt Unless all `1<<24` values are set to distinct and not easily computable values (which seems unlikely, but could be), I think a sparse representation could help.

Comment: I see two things that can be tried, but it's unlikely that they'll amount to much. 1) Compute "const int n_collisions = collions_count * 2;" before the loop, changing the loop to "for(int j = 0; j < n_collions_count; j += 2)". This might eliminate a multiplication on each loop iteration. 2) If `config::THRESHOLD_1` is not a `const`, make a `const` copy of it before the loop. Possible that the compiler might be able to optimize things more, here. Ditto for the other two `config`s. I doubt that any of this will amount to much, but it's worth a shot.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik  your 1st suggestion speeded up the whole process by 30-35%

Comment: Precomputing `collions_count * 2` shouldn't improve anything after -O1. The compiler should precompute by itself, unless you change the value inside the loop. Try compiling and linking with `-flto` instead, sometimes it can enable **massive** optimisations. It depends on the program, but usually I find `-ftlo` more important than `-O3`.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik  @ElderBug maybe I was too optimistic about the 30% but I ended up with precomputing `collions_count * 2`,  removing all configs into `#define ` literals, removing hash assignment (the hash is evaluated in if condidion). I've run the longer benchmark test which shows a 15% improvement total.

Comment: Minor thing, but for integral types, a * 2 == a << 1

Comment: Try different optimization options. Sometimes `-Os` can be faster than `-O[123]` and sometimes `-O2` is faster than `-O3` and `-Ofast` - it all depends on the code being optimized - sometimes using different optimization levels for different files can make sense. Also try LTO.

Comment: Probably won't improve things in a measurable way, but worth a shot: convert your loops to range-based for loops; the range-based loop only evaluates the end condition once rather than on each iteration of the loop.

Comment: @MaciejDonajski Two things come to mind: 

1) See if you can store `(collisions_block[j] & config::MASK_1) << config::SHIFT)` for j = 0 to 511 (based on your number 450) and reuse using an if condition? The branch prediction will fail only one or twice so likely only a  gain. 

2) See if you can split the inner loop into two: the first one does the hash computation and stores it in an array. Second one uses this hash value.  I've never used SIMD instructions myself (and used MKL too long back to remember) but see if you can use SIMD/MKL for the first part of this loop

Comment: I would try to get rid of the lookup `offsets[hash]` and the branch. The reason is that a lookup like that makes it hard for a compiler to optimize code and cause lots of cache misses. It also defeats branch prediction and pipelining. I am not sure if it's possible to get rid of the lookup, but you could get rid of the branch by gathering the objects needed inside the branch in a temporary array and process them in bulk.

Comment: BTW: What is the ratio of in-branch vs not in-branch?

Comment: @0fnt spliting loops slows things down. I do not understand your first suggestion.

Comment: @Florian I cannot find anything faster than the array lookup. How should I measure  in-branch vs not in-branch ratio?

Comment: Add two variables and count them.

Comment: @MaciejDonajski Sorry i meant 4500. You said that collions_count is usually 4500. So how about save the expression above for j : 1->4500 in an array and recompute only the rest? This expression has and shift operations that an be precomputed

Comment: @Florian < 1000 in branch vs > 2000000 not in branch. 3 orders of magnitude.

Comment: @MaciejDonajski, from a clean coding perspective, consider using `constexpr` instead of `#define`.

Answer (score 1):

I identified the performance bottleneck to be the unordered access to array `++offsets[hash]`. It was consuming most of the CPU time (75+%). I achieved 2.5x speed increase by reducing the size of the array from `1<<24` to `1<<21` and experimenting with appropriate `MASKS` configuration.

I will describe briefly how I identified the problem

```
for(size_t i = 0; i < objects.size(); i++) {

  //this part consumes 11% CPU -----> 
  collions_count = database->get_collisions(collisions_block, objects[i].getKey());
  feature1 = objects[i].feature1;
  //<--------

  for(int j = 0; j < collions_count * 2; j += 2) {

    hash = calculate_hash(collisions_block[j], 
      collisions_block[j+1],
      feature1,
      config::MASK_1,
      config::MASK_2
      config::SHIFT);

    if (check_condition(hash, config::THRESHOLD_1)) {

       //... this part consumes < 1% of CPU

    }
  }
}
```

1. Split the critical 2 lines to separate functions for better profiling (be careful to put `__attribute__((noinline))` to prevent gcc from inlining new functions. They will not appear on call stack if inlined)
2. Compile the code with `-g -rdynamic` gcc flags
3. Run sampling pefrormance tool `perf record -p <pid> -F 200 -g --call-graph dwarf -- sleep 60`
4. Convert to [FlameGraph](http://www.brendangregg.com/FlameGraphs/cpuflamegraphs.html) for better readability `perf script | ./stackcollapse-perf.pl > out.perf-folded && ./flamegraph.pl out.perf-folded > graph.svg`
5. Identify most expensive function from flamegraph and optimize it